# How to specify custom a sound scheme within a Windows theme file?

Tags: windows, windows-7, audio, themes, system-sounds

In Windows, one can create custom themes, defined by `.theme` files.  Each theme also contains a ***sound scheme*** for audio cues, as specified in the `Sounds` section of the `.theme` file:

```
[Sounds]
; IDS_SCHEME_DEFAULT
SchemeName=Test_001
```

***How does one specify a custom sound scheme within a `.theme` file?***

I have tried specifying the name of the custom sound scheme here, but Windows always uses its default sound scheme instead.

I have also tried specifying the key name of the custom sound scheme located in the Windows registry at:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Names\`

This also does not work, and yields the same result.

Answer (score 0):

A complete theme is stored in a `.deskthemepack` file.

Here is how to create it :

- Tailor your Windows theme to suite your taste
- Go to *Settings > Personalization > Themes*
- The "Theme: Custom" label indicates that the theme needs to be saved:

  - Click the "Save theme" and enter the theme name,
    which will then be displayed in the themes list
- To save as a `.deskthemepack` file, right click the theme in the list
  and choose "Save theme for sharing"
- Specify the file location and name and click OK.

The `.deskthemepack` file contains the entire theme.
This is a binary file, unlike the `.theme` file which is text.

For more information with screenshots see the article
[Save a Theme as Deskthemepack in Windows 10 Creators Update](https://winaero.com/save-theme-deskthemepack-windows-10/).